# My WebView does not render an HTML page if the screen is off on Oreo

Tags: android, webview, rendering, off-screen

WebView successfully renders html page even if the screen is off on android version pre 8.0/8.1 But it doesn't on Android 8.1. I wonder why? Maybe somebody could give me a hint how can I affect on this behaviour.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to render content if the screen is off?

Comment: I don't want to see web view loading after the screen is switched on. I need that it was already loaded before. So when you switch the screen on, the HTML page  is already ready.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, [`WebSettings.setOffscreenPreRaster(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setOffscreenPreRaster(boolean)) is what you're looking for.